# Maven aggregate POM and parallel build

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, parallel-builds

During non-parallel build aggregate POMs are built last provided there is no parent-child relationships between it and its submodules (correct me if I am wrong).

Is that preserved during parallel builds? Can I assume that root POM is built after all its submodules are built? According to the build logs, it seems like the answer is "no", but maybe I am missing something.

If answer is "no", how can I ensure that aggregate POM is built last? For example, I want to run assembly plugin after all submodules are built (in parallel build)? Of course, I can run separate "mvn -N assembly:assembly" command to assemble built stuff, but is there a way to do that during regular build?

Comment: There is nothing special in my POMs. Standard aggregator POM with a bunch of submodules. Submodules DO NOT inherit from aggregator POM. Assembly plugin configuration is in aggregator POM.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to make the order of builds predictable you need to define a multi-module build which contains dependencies between the module which will automatically resolved by maven and will correctly change the order in the reactor for building.